# Problem creating association with a multi-pk model

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a problem, I have two models; "GeoBlocking" and "Countries", and an association:

GeoBlockingModel:

```
const TYPE_BLACK = 0x10;
const TYPE_WHITE = 0x20;

export const ETYPE_CONTENT = 0x10;

export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => {

    const GeoBlockingModel = sequelize.define('GeoBlocking', {

        targetUUID: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            primaryKey: true,
        },

        entityType: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
            primaryKey: true,
            validate: {
                isIn: {
                    args: [[
                        ETYPE_CONTENT,
                    ]],
                    msg: `Unknow entity type`,
                },
            },
        },

        type: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: TYPE_BLACK,
            validate: {
                isIn: {
                    args: [[
                        TYPE_BLACK,
                        TYPE_WHITE,
                    ]],
                    msg: `Unknow type`,
                },
            },
        },
    }
    //...
```

Association:

```
    GeoBlockingModel.associate = function(models) {
        CountryModel = models.countries;

        GeoBlockingModel.belongsToMany(CountryModel, {
            as: 'countries',
            through: {
                model: 'GeoBlockingCountry',
                timestamps: true,
                paranoid: false,
            },
            // foreignKey: ['targetUUID', 'entityType'],
            constraints: true,
        });
    };
```

The problem is, `GeoBlocking` model has two primary key, `entityType` and `targetUUID`. And the through model is created with only one field association:

```
CREATE TABLE `GeoBlockingCountry` (
    `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `GeoBlockingTargetUUID` UUID NOT NULL REFERENCES `GeoBlockings` (`targetUUID`)
          ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    `CountryId` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL REFERENCES `Countries` (`id`)
           ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (`GeoBlockingTargetUUID`, `CountryId`))
```

If I uncomment `// foreignKey: ['targetUUID', 'entityType'],`, the field is craeted as `undefined`.

Some idea?